# Is there a way to control the intensity of the iPhone vibration in real time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swiftui

For example, I would like to make a slider that starts off at 0 intensity vibration. As the user slides the slider closer to 100, the vibration increases in real time, until they release the slider, at which time the vibration should stop.

Answer (score 4):

There is [CoreHaptics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics) framework that release last year for you

You can see sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics/updating_continuous_and_transient_haptic_parameters_in_real_time)